# Issue with "Advanced search options" help page link in the "What is a locked post?" help page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, help-center, locked-questions

In the end of the [What is a locked post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) help page of every Stack Exchange site, there is a link [Advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), which is redirecting to the "How do I search?" help page.

The "Advanced search options" link in the "locked post" help page of sites, other than Meta Stack Exchange are also pointing to Meta Stack Exchange Search page only. For example, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) and [Database Administrators SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts). Something as follows:

> **See also:**
>
> - [Advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

The problem is, "Deleted Posts" section in the search help page is linked to the Meta Stack Exchange's "Moderator Tools" and "Site Moderators" pages only. Something as follows:

> **Deleted Posts (requires 10,000 reputation)**
>
> When you earn the [Access to Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, ...
>
> ....
>
> [Site Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) may use this operator to ...

Since we have the separate "Advanced search options" pages for the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and [Database Administrator SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/searching), these site specific help pages will correctly redirect to their site's "Moderator Tools" and "Site Moderators" pages.

So in all the Stack Exchange site's "What is a locked post?" page should contains "Advanced search options" link as their site's search help page, instead of the Meta Stack Exchange site's search help page.
Can this be updated?